# spark error when numRow

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I am running spark in standalone mode. I do the following commands to create a RowMatrix from a csv file.

```
scala> val data = sc.textFile("/home/donbeo/Documents/dataset/time_series/PSI_TS_clean.csv")
15/03/30 00:43:13 INFO MemoryStore: ensureFreeSpace(32840) called with curMem=52133, maxMem=278302556
15/03/30 00:43:13 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_5 stored as values in memory (estimated size 32.1 KB, free 265.3 MB)
15/03/30 00:43:13 INFO MemoryStore: ensureFreeSpace(4959) called with curMem=84973, maxMem=278302556
15/03/30 00:43:13 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_5_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 4.8 KB, free 265.3 MB)
15/03/30 00:43:13 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_5_piece0 in memory on localhost:53497 (size: 4.8 KB, free: 265.4 MB)
15/03/30 00:43:13 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Updated info of block broadcast_5_piece0
15/03/30 00:43:13 INFO SparkContext: Created broadcast 5 from textFile at <console>:22
data: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = /home/donbeo/Documents/dataset/time_series/PSI_TS_clean.csv MappedRDD[5] at textFile at <console>:22

scala> val num_data = data.map(line => line.split(',').tail.map(x=>x.toDouble))
15/03/30 00:43:23 INFO BlockManager: Removing broadcast 4
15/03/30 00:43:23 INFO BlockManager: Removing block broadcast_4
15/03/30 00:43:23 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_4 of size 2896 dropped from memory (free 278215520)
15/03/30 00:43:23 INFO BlockManager: Removing block broadcast_4_piece0
15/03/30 00:43:23 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_4_piece0 of size 2062 dropped from memory (free 278217582)
15/03/30 00:43:23 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_4_piece0 on localhost:53497 in memory (size: 2.0 KB, free: 265.4 MB)
15/03/30 00:43:23 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Updated info of block broadcast_4_piece0
15/03/30 00:43:23 INFO ContextCleaner: Cleaned broadcast 4
num_data: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Array[Double]] = MappedRDD[6] at map at <console>:33

scala>   val v = num_data map (line=> Vectors.dense(line))
v: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector] = MappedRDD[7] at map at <console>:35

scala>   val x = new RowMatrix(v)
x: org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.distributed.RowMatrix = org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.distributed.RowMatrix@52e75656

scala>
```

and then I get the following error:

```
scala> x.numRows
15/03/30 00:46:32 INFO FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
15/03/30 00:46:32 INFO SparkContext: Starting job: count at RowMatrix.scala:76
15/03/30 00:46:32 INFO DAGScheduler: Got job 4 (count at RowMatrix.scala:76) with 138 output partitions (allowLocal=false)
15/03/30 00:46:32 INFO DAGScheduler: Final stage: Stage 4(count at RowMatrix.scala:76)
15/03/30 00:46:32 INFO DAGScheduler: Parents of final stage: List()
15/03/30 00:46:32 INFO DAGScheduler: Missing parents: List()
15/03/30 00:46:32 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting Stage 4 (MappedRDD[7] at map at <console>:35), which has no missing parents
15/03/30 00:46:32 INFO MemoryStore: ensureFreeSpace(2904) called with curMem=84974, maxMem=278302556
15/03/30 00:46:32 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_6 stored as values in memory (estimated size 2.8 KB, free 265.3 MB)
15/03/30 00:46:32 INFO MemoryStore: ensureFreeSpace(2061) called with curMem=87878, maxMem=278302556
15/03/30 00:46:32 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_6_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 2.0 KB, free 265.3 MB)
15/03/30 00:46:32 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_6_piece0 in memory on localhost:53497 (size: 2.0 KB, free: 265.4 MB)
15/03/30 00:46:32 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Updated info of block broadcast_6_piece0
15/03/30 00:46:32 INFO SparkContext: Created broadcast 6 from broadcast at DAGScheduler.scala:838
15/03/30 00:46:32 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting 138 missing tasks from Stage 4 (MappedRDD[7] at map at <console>:35)
15/03/30 00:46:32 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Adding task set 4.0 with 138 tasks
15/03/30 00:46:32 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.0 in stage 4.0 (TID 8, localhost, PROCESS_LOCAL, 1329 bytes)
15/03/30 00:46:32 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 1.0 in stage 4.0 (TID 9, localhost, PROCESS_LOCAL, 1329 bytes)
15/03/30 00:46:32 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 2.0 in stage 4.0 (TID 10, localhost, PROCESS_LOCAL, 1329 bytes)
15/03/30 00:46:32 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 3.0 in stage 4.0 (TID 11, localhost, PROCESS_LOCAL, 1329 bytes)
15/03/30 00:46:32 INFO Executor: Running task 0.0 in stage 4.0 (TID 8)
15/03/30 00:46:32 INFO Executor: Running task 1.0 in stage 4.0 (TID 9)
15/03/30 00:46:32 INFO Executor: Running task 2.0 in stage 4.0 (TID 10)
15/03/30 00:46:32 INFO Executor: Running task 3.0 in stage 4.0 (TID 11)
15/03/30 00:46:32 INFO HadoopRDD: Input split: file:/home/donbeo/Documents/dataset/time_series/PSI_TS_clean.csv:100663296+33554432
15/03/30 00:46:32 INFO HadoopRDD: Input split: file:/home/donbeo/Documents/dataset/time_series/PSI_TS_clean.csv:0+33554432
15/03/30 00:46:32 INFO HadoopRDD: Input split: file:/home/donbeo/Documents/dataset/time_series/PSI_TS_clean.csv:33554432+33554432
15/03/30 00:46:32 INFO HadoopRDD: Input split: file:/home/donbeo/Documents/dataset/time_series/PSI_TS_clean.csv:67108864+33554432
15/03/30 00:46:32 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 2.0 in stage 4.0 (TID 10)
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "SensorOnly"
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1250)
    at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:540)
    at scala.collection.immutable.StringLike$class.toDouble(StringLike.scala:232)
    at scala.collection.immutable.StringOps.toDouble(StringOps.scala:31)
    at $line201.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(<console>:33)
    at $line201.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(<console>:33)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:108)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.map(ArrayOps.scala:108)
    at $line201.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$anonfun$1.apply(<console>:33)
    at $line201.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$anonfun$1.apply(<console>:33)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.getIteratorSize(Utils.scala:1401)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$count$1.apply(RDD.scala:927)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$count$1.apply(RDD.scala:927)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$4.apply(SparkContext.scala:1353)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$4.apply(SparkContext.scala:1353)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:61)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:200)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
15/03/30 00:46:32 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 1.0 in stage 4.0 (TID 9)
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "SensorOnly"
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1250)
    at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:540)
    at scala.collection.immutable.StringLike$class.toDouble(StringLike.scala:232)
    at scala.collection.immutable.StringOps.toDouble(StringOps.scala:31)
    at $line201.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(<console>:33)
    at $line201.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(<console>:33)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:108)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.map(ArrayOps.scala:108)
    at $line201.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$anonfun$1.apply(<console>:33)
    at $line201.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$anonfun$1.apply(<console>:33)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.getIteratorSize(Utils.scala:1401)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$count$1.apply(RDD.scala:927)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$count$1.apply(RDD.scala:927)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$4.apply(SparkContext.scala:1353)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$4.apply(SparkContext.scala:1353)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:61)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:200)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
15/03/30 00:46:32 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 4.0 in stage 4.0 (TID 12, localhost, PROCESS_LOCAL, 1329 bytes)
15/03/30 00:46:32 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 5.0 in stage 4.0 (TID 13, localhost, PROCESS_LOCAL, 1329 bytes)
15/03/30 00:46:32 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 2.0 in stage 4.0 (TID 10, localhost): java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "SensorOnly"
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1250)
    at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:540)
    at scala.collection.immutable.StringLike$class.toDouble(StringLike.scala:232)
    at scala.collection.immutable.StringOps.toDouble(StringOps.scala:31)
    at $line201.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(<console>:33)
    at $line201.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(<console>:33)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:108)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.map(ArrayOps.scala:108)
    at $line201.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$anonfun$1.apply(<console>:33)
    at $line201.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$anonfun$1.apply(<console>:33)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.getIteratorSize(Utils.scala:1401)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$count$1.apply(RDD.scala:927)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$count$1.apply(RDD.scala:927)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$4.apply(SparkContext.scala:1353)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$4.apply(SparkContext.scala:1353)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:61)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:200)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

15/03/30 00:46:32 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 2 in stage 4.0 failed 1 times; aborting job
15/03/30 00:46:32 INFO Executor: Running task 5.0 in stage 4.0 (TID 13)
15/03/30 00:46:32 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Cancelling stage 4
15/03/30 00:46:32 INFO Executor: Running task 4.0 in stage 4.0 (TID 12)
15/03/30 00:46:32 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Stage 4 was cancelled
15/03/30 00:46:32 INFO Executor: Executor is trying to kill task 4.0 in stage 4.0 (TID 12)
15/03/30 00:46:32 INFO DAGScheduler: Job 4 failed: count at RowMatrix.scala:76, took 0.073135 s
15/03/30 00:46:32 INFO Executor: Executor is trying to kill task 5.0 in stage 4.0 (TID 13)
15/03/30 00:46:32 INFO Executor: Executor is trying to kill task 3.0 in stage 4.0 (TID 11)
15/03/30 00:46:32 INFO Executor: Executor is trying to kill task 0.0 in stage 4.0 (TID 8)
15/03/30 00:46:32 INFO Executor: Executor killed task 0.0 in stage 4.0 (TID 8)
15/03/30 00:46:32 INFO Executor: Executor killed task 3.0 in stage 4.0 (TID 11)
15/03/30 00:46:32 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 4.0 (TID 8, localhost): TaskKilled (killed intentionally)
15/03/30 00:46:32 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 4.0 in stage 4.0 (TID 12)
org.apache.spark.TaskKilledException
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:191)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
15/03/30 00:46:32 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 5.0 in stage 4.0 (TID 13)
org.apache.spark.TaskKilledException
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:191)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
15/03/30 00:46:32 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 5.0 in stage 4.0 (TID 13, localhost): org.apache.spark.TaskKilledException
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:191)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

15/03/30 00:46:32 INFO TaskSetManager: Lost task 4.0 in stage 4.0 (TID 12) on executor localhost: org.apache.spark.TaskKilledException (null) [duplicate 1]
15/03/30 00:46:32 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Removed TaskSet 4.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool 
15/03/30 00:46:32 INFO TaskSetManager: Lost task 1.0 in stage 4.0 (TID 9) on executor localhost: java.lang.NumberFormatException (For input string: "SensorOnly") [duplicate 1]
15/03/30 00:46:32 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Removed TaskSet 4.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool 
15/03/30 00:46:32 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 3.0 in stage 4.0 (TID 11, localhost): TaskKilled (killed intentionally)
15/03/30 00:46:32 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Removed TaskSet 4.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool 
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 2 in stage 4.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 2.0 in stage 4.0 (TID 10, localhost): java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "SensorOnly"
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1250)
    at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:540)
    at scala.collection.immutable.StringLike$class.toDouble(StringLike.scala:232)
    at scala.collection.immutable.StringOps.toDouble(StringOps.scala:31)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(<console>:33)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(<console>:33)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:108)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.map(ArrayOps.scala:108)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$anonfun$1.apply(<console>:33)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$anonfun$1.apply(<console>:33)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.getIteratorSize(Utils.scala:1401)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$count$1.apply(RDD.scala:927)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$count$1.apply(RDD.scala:927)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$4.apply(SparkContext.scala:1353)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$4.apply(SparkContext.scala:1353)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:61)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:200)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1214)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1203)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1202)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1202)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:696)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:696)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:696)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessActor$$anonfun$receive$2.applyOrElse(DAGScheduler.scala:1420)
    at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:465)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessActor.aroundReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1375)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:516)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:487)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:238)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:220)
    at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:393)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)


scala>
```

Why do I get this error and how can I solve the problem?

Comment: Is there a header row at the top of the CSV that you need to skip over?

Comment: I am not 100 % sure about that. Now I am using spark 1.3 and a new csv file where I am sure that there are not headers and it is working. If you are interested I can check the old file.